# Removing www. and .com from string using regex

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I want to remove 'www.' and '.com' from this string 'www.example.com'

I want to do it in one step with regex but I am still learn regex. Any help and explanation of the flags and syntax will be appreciated so I can get an understanding of what it is doing.

Comment: Why do neophytes always want to pick up the heaviest possible hammer?

Comment: Please find an online regex tutorial and consult that. Here we do not really write tutorials - we help with what you already got. (not to mention regex is not certainly the best option in this case)

Comment: Do you want to remove only `.com`? Or Any TLD (`.fr`, `.org`)?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1345072659&sr=8-1&keywords=regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('#^www\.|\.com$#', '', 'www.example.com');
```

Start from here: http://rubular.com/r/MvyPO9ijnQ

But you really shouldn't be doing that with regexp, and especially not in one one fall-swoop whatever it means.

Take a look at the: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php (I know you want to learn regexp by parsing URL, but don't).

Comment: FYI: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one_fell_swoop

Comment: @KendallFrey fell === fall (false) but thanks

Comment: @webarto The parse_url() function will not separate the www. and .com from the domain. The string 'www.domain.com' will show up as the path val.

Comment: @csteel hopefully, this might help you in learning process http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.png

Answer (score 3):

Do not use regex. There are simpler solutions available.

Try this:

```
$theString = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
$theName = explode('.', $theString)[1];
```

Comment: note: that syntax only works in php 5.4

Comment: @KendallFrey This will work, but I want to do it in one line so that it is clean. Thanks for the insight tho! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @csteel This is in one line. The first line is just declaring a variable (which would most likely be gotten somewhere else).