# Regex to remove all urls which ends with .com but may or may not start with http

Tags: java, regex

What is a regex to match URLs which end with ".com" or ".co.in" so they may be removed. The URLs may or may not necessarily start with "www" or "http".

Ex xyz.com or http://dfdsf.co.in or ABCD.co.in

Comment: Remove from what? A string? A list? Are the URL's delimited?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing www. and .com from string using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978584/removing-www-and-com-from-string-using-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex \S*\.com\b|\S*\.co.in\b would match any URL ending in .com or .co.in. You could use

```
String myInputString = "I love google.com really";
String myReplacedString = myInputString.replaceAll("\\S*\\.com\\b|\\S*\\.co.in\\b", "");
```

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm and use this to test the regex: http://fiddle.re/w5062a

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html for more regex information

Updated: changed based on question clarification

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am sorry I forgot to mention that the text can be a long string like "Hello World google.com is amazing!!"

Comment: Do you want to just remove the url from the string or do you want to detect when the string contains a url so that you can do or not do something?

Comment: I actually want to remove the URL. Now it may appear anywhere in the string, in the beginning, middle or end.

Comment: Edited to match requirements better.

Comment: No probs. could you mark the answer as accepted and/or up vote?